# Rails 5.2 save method in credentials?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, credentials

Rails 5.2 credententials
Can I save method in Credentials?

for example

Post.rb

```
def score_count
  Rails.application.credentials.score_count
end
```

Credentials.yml.enc

```
score_count: 'score_count...'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly it is not recommended but still you can accomplish this functionality by saving your method name in credentials.yml.enc and then call it as

```
send(Rails.application.credentials.score_count)
```

or

```
eval("#{Rails.application.credentials.score_count}")
```